# Laurent Series of $(z^2-1)^{-2}$

Tags: complex-numbers, laurent-series

I have problems to determine the Laurent series of the function $(z^2-1)^{-2}$ in the regions:

$$0<|z-1|<2$$
and
$$|z+1|>2$$.

My idea was as follows:

$$\frac{1}{z^2-1}=\frac{1}{4z(z-1)^2}-\frac{1}{4z(z+1)^2}$$

However, this procedure only makes it harder to make the series, and tried to do it by Taylor.

Answer (score 2):

Make a partial fraction decomposition:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{z^2-1} &= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{1}{z+1}\right)\\
\frac{1}{(z^2-1)^2} &= \frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{(z-1)^2} - \frac{2}{z^2-1} + \frac{1}{(z+1)^2}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{(z-1)^2} - \frac{1}{z-1} + \frac{1}{z+1} + \frac{1}{(z+1)^2}\right).
\end{align}$$

Each of these terms can be expanded easily in the regions as geometric series (possibly once differentiated), when they can't remain as is.

Comment: Thank you very much, your idea is very elegant, thanks